# Why Fluentd-elasticsearch cannot send logs to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, fluentd, efk

I have deployed EFK stack on Kubernetes and I get following error messages and looks like Fluentd cannot communicate with elasticsearch.

**[warn]: [elasticsearch] Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution (SocketError)**

**[warn]: [elasticsearch] Remaining retry: 11. Retry to communicate after 16 second(s)**

Deploying different Helm charts makes any difference!!? Deployed kiwigrid/fluentd-elasticsearch for Fluentd and bitnami/elasticsearch for elasticsearch and stable/kibana for Kibana. However, Ping or SSH to fluentd is possible from my external Linux machine. EFK stack runs inside same namespace. Rancher tool monitors whole cluster therefore I see my Fluentd logs. Loadbalancer IP for Kibana and Elasticsearch is set. Able to see Kibana UI page.

[image: elasticsearch-elasticsearch-master-1 1/1 Running 0 24h fluentd-elasticsearch-4q6cx 1/1 Running 3 47m]

Anybody who can support in this problem? pretty new to K8s.

Comment: Are you able to `ping` or `ssh` to Elasticsearch's machine?

Comment: @Azeem Yes, I can go inside container from my local Linux machine and see some files: "kubectl exec -it elasticsearch-elasticsearch-master-1 -n logging -- bash"

Comment: But, are you able to ping it from an external machine (preferably, where fluentd resides)? I'm assuming that the container's IP has already been exposed.

Comment: Yes, I am using loadbalancer IP to expose to end-user. and EFK stack resides on same namespace.

Comment: Right. Did you try to send logs through some command-line tool for testing?

Comment: I see logs of elasticsearch container in Rancher tool where I can monitor whole cluster

Comment: How about manually sending a log e.g. using `curl`?

Comment: Okay. You should add this information in your question as well. Those errors show that it's a connectivity issue but you've already verified that it's working for other stuff. I'd suggest running fluentd with`-v` or `-vv` flag and observe debug issues. If the connectivity issue still persists even after multiple retries, open an issue for this plugin on fluentd GitHub repo.

Comment: @Azeem Thank you for valuable suggestions. I run fluentd -v and  -vv but still same error messages which I mentioned inside question.